# How to add an image which disappears after a transition?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I created a game on different levels. If the user reaches a certain gameScore an alertButton should pop up(that worked already), but as soon as the user switches scenes the button should disappear. With my code, the button doesn´t disappear. How can I let the image appear just once?

Here is my code:

```
var alertButton = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "AlertButton")
var totalGameScore = 0

class Game: SKScene {
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
if totalGameScore > 50 { //alert button appears and should disappear after scene changes 
self.addChild(alertButton)
}
if totalGameScore > 100 { //alert button appears again and should disappear after scene changes
self.addChild(alertButton)
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is that the alertbutton appears once totalGameScore > 50.  The second if is actually going to add a second button when totalGameScore > 100 because boths ifs will execute.

To handle this situation you should have two flags:

```
var hasShown50ScoreButton = false
var hasShow100ScoreButton = false
```

then you check:

```
class Game: SKScene {
   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      if totalGameScore > 50  && hasShown50ScoreButton == false {
         self.addChild(alertButton)
         hasShown50ScoreButton = true
      } else if totalGameScore > 100 && hasShown100ScoreButton == false {
        self.addChild(alertButton)
        hasShown100ScoreButton = true
      } else if alertButton.superview != nil {
        aleterButton.removeFromSuperview()
     }
}
```